# Create table around text

Tags: vim, plugins, tabular

I have a list of words every is on its own line. This is the first column of a table. I'd like to create second column by hand.

I'd like to use some plugin now, that will create an ASCII table around the text, so I have nice formatting (the starting letters in each column should be in one "vertical line" or I should be able to quickly move to the correct position with one shortcut).

Is there such a plugin for vim that eases editing such tables and controls the formatting?

Comment: Just to be clear are you wanting lines around the table?  Or just tabulated text?

Comment: @Benj Tabulated text would be good, but lines around (at least in vertical direction) would be even better.

Comment: xralf I don't have a vim plugin but I do have a nifty perl script which can be used on a block inside vim if that helps?  It can convert a block of comma seperated text into a nicely formatted table and then back again so that you can edit it?

Comment: @Benj I'm looking for something more universal, like the org-mode for Emacs editor for creating tables. I can also create some scripts but the plugin should be able format while editing.

Comment: I've put the script up anyway, you can use it while editing by using vim's filter command "!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want text alignment into table format, I use this and it works well:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294

I wrote a [command line tool](http://pastebin.com/BarvM7DQ) a few years ago which does more closely what you want:

It allows you to edit a table in CSV format:

```
1,my table,another field
2,my table,yet another field
```

Then select the block in vim, and filter it using:

```
'<,'>!~/scripts/tab
```

This then gives you:

```
------------------------------------
| 1 | my table | another field     |
| 2 | my table | yet another field |
------------------------------------
```

If you want to edit the table again, you can select the whole table and repeat with `untab` (which is just a symlink -> tab) which converts the table back to CSV again so that you can edit.

There's also various other options:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Command/Option | Purpose                                              |
|----------------|------------------------------------------------------|
| tab            | Reads from stdin and tabulates comma seperated input |
| tab <-t>       | Tabulates input and assumes first row are titles     |
| tab <-h>       | Prints this help                                     |
| tab <-nb>      | Tabulates without a border                           |
| tab <-fw X>    | Wrap fields greater than X big don't break words     |
| tab <-fs X>    | Wrap fields greater than X big and break words       |
| tab <-vp X>    | Vertically pad table by X lines                      |
| tab <-hp X>    | Horizontally pad fields by X chars                   |
| tab <-b X>     | Tabulates with a border made from char X             |
|----------------|------------------------------------------------------|
| untab          | Reads from stdin and untabulates table input         |
| untab <-b X>   | Untabulate a table with border char X                |
| untab <-nb>    | Untabulate a borderless table                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @Benj Thank you, this will be sufficient for my recent editing, I will try it, but I'm interested if something like org-mode in Emacs exist that has even more possibilities for effective table editing and works interactively while editing (not in batch).

Comment: @xralf I don't believe there are any vim table plugins that are as sophisticated as org-mode.