# select different rows from grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of repeated measurements over days for variables t, l and c. I am trying to calculate the difference in days between the peaks for t, and l/c. I have managed to find the day of peak measurement, but I am not sure how I can get these all on the same line so that I can calculate the day difference.

```
Record | day | t      | day_tmax | l   | day_lmax | c     | day_cmax
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1   | 40.5   | NA       | 2   | NA       | 1.6   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 2   | 136.8  | 2        | 2.5 | 2        | 190.6 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 3   | 102.7  | NA       | 1.6 | NA       | 375.8 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 4   | 55.1   | NA       | 1.6 | NA       | 515.5 | 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 5   | 32.3   | NA       | 1.7 | NA       | 411.2 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 6   | 27.4   | NA       | 1.5 | NA       | 235.7 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 7   | 17.7   | NA       | 1.1 | NA       | 187.1 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 8   | 23     | NA       | 1.4 | NA       | 257   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 9   | 17.2   | NA       | 1.4 | NA       | 170.5 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 10  | 12.1   | NA       | 0.6 | NA       | 162.1 | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 1   | 72.2   | NA       | 0.9 | 1        | 2.4   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 2   | 54.3   | NA       | 0.8 | na       | 3.9   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 3   | 64.4   | NA       | 0.7 | NA       | 4.6   | 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 4   | 63.1   | NA       | 0.5 | NA       | 3.1   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 5   | 65.2   | NA       | 0.3 | NA       | 4.5   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 6   | 66.5   | NA       | 0.2 | NA       | 4.6   | 6
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 7   | 81.5   | 7        | 0.2 | NA       | 3.5   | NA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know in dplyr:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(record) %>% mutate(day_tmax = nth(day_tmax,2))
```

But is there a way to do this when the position of the original variable varies?

Comment: could you format your data such that its aligned well!. just add 4 spaces :)

Comment: @joel.wilson sorry, I realise that's annoying, I did ask for help with that in the question. Thank you user2100721

Comment: hey..could you explain more on how you want the output to be like?

Comment: @Annemarie To know about making a table at stackoverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables . Use VIM to make an ascii table, use http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/363/how-can-i-easily-create-and-maintain-tables   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402680/create-table-around-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
df%>%
  group_by(Record)%>%
  mutate(diff_peak_t_lc=day[which.max(t)]-day[which.max(l/c)])
```

With `day[which.max(t)]` giving you the `day` for which `t` is at its peak and `day[which.max(l/c)]` giving you the `day` for which `l/c` is at its peak.

**edit:** Followed Paul Hiemstra's suggestion.

Comment: Nice! You could even replace `1/c==max(1/c)` by `which.max(1/c)`.

Comment: @Haboryme Fantastic, that's exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks very much